# ExecuteEntityQuery and CustomMeta

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I am trying to retrieve a list of components (including metadata) using the ExecuteEntityQuery method.

Unfortunately the CustomMeta property never gets populated and therefore I am having iterate over all items in the list and retrieve the CustomMeta for each one - serious performance issue.

Is there a way I can retrieve the CustomMeta for a list of components without hitting the db for every item in the list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As [this page in the documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_0E815EA0BAF543DB99BAC0C7E98BE26A) says `ExecuteEntityQuery`:

> Returns an array of objects matching the query. Use `executeQuery` if you need direct access to the items' properties.

To reduce the number of database hits, also consider using Tridion's Object Cache. You can fit a surprisingly large amount of metadata into a regularly sized cache.

Comment: I did notice that in the documentation but it does not give you "direct access to the object properties" as it only returns each items id and from there you need to query each items meta in a loop.

Comment: I will check yo see if we are using the object cache but would be surprised if not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the custom meta does not get populated automatically for efficiency's sake. An alternative is to use the content delivery web service (OData). This does allow you to get all the CustomMeta of a range of items in one query.

A simple example which gives you all components including custom metadata in a given publication:

```
http://mysite/odata.svc/Publications(30)/Components?$expand=CustomMeta
```

Comment: I didn't think of using the odata service. I believe the service offers some performance issues of it own - but I will take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @dylman79 I would give it a shot. Web APIs are not necessarily slower than java / .net APIs.